# C++: iterator adaptor bounding the iterator within a range of iterators?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, iterator, adaptor

Suppose I have two iterators, which span entire stl-like container or its contiguous part, thus defining a range. This pair of iterators would be immutable. Then I would like to have a third, mutable iterator, which will point to any of the elements being part of the range.
This leads me to having an adaptor, for instance (metacode):

```
Adaptor<Iterator>:
==================
   + Iterator: begin
   + Iterator: end
   + Iterator: current
```

if `current==begin` then `std::prev(adaptor)` doesn't change `current` and still equals `begin`
if `current==end` then `std::next(adaptor)` doesn't change `current` and it still equals `end`

I tried to find out-of-the-shelf solutions in STL and Boost, but so far (might be my vocab/jargon limitation) I can't find any.
Should I implement such adaptor from scratch myself or I am missing some stl/boost goodies out there?
Thanks.

Comment: Such itetators would violate most people's assumptions about how iterators should behave. For example `it+1-1 == it` should hold whenever both sides are defined.

Comment: @n.m. does that hold when an iterator is equal to `end` on a container? I'd expect it to be UB.

Comment: @MarkRansom ... whenever both sides are defined I said. This attempt is similar to extending division such that division by zero is defined. Such attempts are useless because the resulting structure cannot obey the laws of arithmetic.

Comment: I wonder what's the use case for such iterators... Can you give us an example?

Comment: I am tempted to have the iterator bound with the range within which it operates. Ok - this wicked arithmetics doesn't make much sense for the adaptor, but some sort of a wrapper object which would hold information on the valid range of data would suffice. Right now it is a bit awkward with the code I am working with to pass to some functions the iterator itself, and the two iterators which correspond to begin/end respectively. Binding those three together seems like an obvious improvement. Boost has got iterator_range but with it I am only halfway there.

Answer (score 0):

It would not be possible to implement this as an iterator. For `std::prev/next` to work on it, it must be a "bidirectional iterator" (in the sense of fulfilling all the requirements of the "bidirectional iterator" model). One of those requirements is "`--r == --s` implies `r == s`." But, of course, that wouldn't be true for two such iterators if one were immediately after `begin` and the other one were at `begin`.